# Informix 11.50 Connection Error ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N using Informix client sdk 3.5

Tags: .net-4.0, informix

I have a Windows server 2008 R2 64 bit with a VMware instance of Informix Dynmic Server 11.50 virtual appliance 32bit running.
Using the default database server provided in the virtual appliance i have created a database and a table inside it.
I installed the Informix Client SDK 3.5 and the informix data server provider Drivers on the windows server.
I setup the server connection on the windows server using setnet tool.
**I tested the connection with the connect test demo tool of the SDK and the query executed successfully.**
Now when I am testing the .Net provider driver by running the testconn.40_32.exe with the following connection String:

> **testconn40_32.exe -dtc "Database=safdata; Server=192.168.154.128:9088; User ID=root; Password=root"**

I get following error:

> Unable to open socket to server:
>
> **ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N**  A communication error has been detected. Communic
>   ation protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".
>   Location where the error was detected: "192.168.154.128".  Communication functio
>   n detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".
>   SQLSTATE=08001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the client SDK and all other drivers.. re-installed only the client SDK and it worked. The client drivers were conflicting with other versions of the driver I had installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried both tests from the same machine? If not then maybe you cannot go through firewall or other network device.

If you run tests on the same machine the server works then instead of `192.168.154.128` use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. You can also check if Informix listens on port 9088 using `netstat` command or tool like TCView or ProcessExplorer.

Comment: There is no firewall installed, on windows server the default firewall is turned off. The virtual appliance is running on the same machine that is trying to connect, since it is a virtual machine, it has to connect via the network card, so localhost invalid. On the database server, informix is listening on port 9088

Comment: With ClientSDK there is ODBC driver. Try configure it with ODBC manager. There is "Apply & Test connection" button.

Comment: I go it... I uninstalled the client SDK and all other drivers.. re-installed only the client SDK and it worked.